# Unable to run .Net core application in Docker using Azure AD Authentication

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c

Hi I have developed web application in .netcore. I am running it in container. I am using Azure AD authentication. Below is my authentication code.

```
services.AddAuthentication(o =>
               {
                   o.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
               })
               .AddJwtBearer(o =>
               {   
                   o.Authority = Configuration["Authentication:Authority"];
                   o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                   {  
                       ValidAudiences = new List<string>
                       {
                            Configuration["Authentication:AppIdUri"],
                            Configuration["Authentication:ClientId"]
                       }
                   };
               });
               services.AddMvc(options =>
                {

                 var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();
                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
               })
               .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
```

Whenever I hit api I get below error in debug tab.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://sts.windows.net/448d-b259-98a44d112f7c/.well-known/openid-configuration'. ---> System.IO.IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: 'https://sts.windows.net/cba8ca03-8b95-448d-b259-98a44d112f7c/.well-known/openid-configuration'. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Resource temporarily unavailable ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Resource temporarily unavailable
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.WaitForCreatedConnectionAsync(ValueTask`1 creationTask)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String address, CancellationToken cancel)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String address, CancellationToken cancel)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever.GetAsync(String address, IDocumentRetriever retriever, CancellationToken cancel)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.AuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIIndexMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
[40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 20110.119ms 500 text/html; charset=utf-8
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 20110.119ms 500 text/html; charset=utf-8
```

Below is my docker file.

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["DigiPlatform/DigiPlatform.csproj", "DigiPlatform/"]
RUN dotnet restore "DigiPlatform/DigiPlatform.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/DigiPlatform"
RUN dotnet build "DigiPlatform.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "DigiPlatform.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DigiPlatform.dll"]
```

I am struggling very hard to find out this issue! Whenever I hit api every time above exception will come. Can someone help me figure out this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: you're opein config url is not valid: https://sts.windows.net/448d-b259-98a44d112f7c/.well-known/openid-configuration. check the url below it says that you dont have a susbcription associated to this tenant or that the tentnat does not exists....

Comment: Hi Thomas, I tried to open url in broser and it is working. Also In iis it works great. Only inside docker there is problem

Comment: Usually `https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant-id` is used as authority. Though could be yours works as well, but there is something blocking the outbound call.

Comment: My auth url is https://sts.windows.net/cba8ca03-8b95. Is this correct

Comment: The tenant-id is found by going to the Azure Active Directory -> Properties then look for a field called Directory-Id. The URL you posted above looks too short to be a Tenant-Id. Where did you get the id from ?

Comment: Hi Darren. I have not added complete tenant id there. It’s half only.

Comment: Can you show your Dockerfile which you use to create the docker image?

Comment: Sure. I will add it now

Comment: It seems there is no problem with your Dockerfile, just the first `FROM` is useless. How do you run the image? And how does your application work?

Comment: I am using VS2017. I select docker and click run.

Comment: Why not add your entire tenant id, it’s public info. The error is clear, incorrect tenant id in Configuration["Authentication:Authority"];. If you look in you select your B2C policy in the Azure portal, and click “run now”, it’ll show the correct well known open id config endpoint with a GUID that represents your tenant id.